# How to programmatically link account for Alexa Skill from my server

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

1. I already have a Alexa skill and build back end server with my own oauth for account linking from Alexa.
2. I also have a mobile app allow user logged in my own back end server.

I want after user login my own app and LWA, my back end server can programmatically enable skill and linking account with our Alexa skill. (User don't need open Alexa and link account from Alexa)

Comment: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/app-to-app-account-linking-starting-from-your-app.html

Comment: This flow not allowed link account from back end server. I found it work with fitbit. But I can not found official documents for it.

Comment: Yes you can, there is literally a schema explaining it on that same [doc](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/app-to-app-account-linking-starting-from-your-app.html#how-it-works)